# About convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n$ be sequence of functions defined by:
$$
f_n = \begin{cases} \cos(nx) & x\geq 1/n \\
             x & x<1/n
\end{cases}
$$
My question is that if this sequence have subsequences which are converging to every points  then what's the expression of that?My second question is that is there any subsequence converging to $0$ at every points of domain? And the third question is what kind of sequence is this?
Thanks!
Ok, I want to add something here, these $f_n$ are defined on E={1/m : m∈ℕ}.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "x>=1/n=x", could this be elaborated? This is probably just a typo, but also, do try to use some LaTeX, as it is generally more readable.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne The question was poorly formatted. I submitted an edit to improve readability. I believe the OP was trying to give a piecewise definition for $f_n(x)$

Comment: Sorry for the problem!

Comment: In which sense are we talking about convergence of functions here? Pointwise? Uniform? Convergence with respect to some $p$-norm? It's not hard to see, for example, that the whole sequence (and hence every subsequence) converges pointwise.

Comment: I want know to more about of this type of sequence,,is there any book or papers or some theoretical,,,if anyone have those,, please suggest !!!

Comment: Of course it's about pointwise

Comment: I add some edits! Please see now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are your questions,

Q 1) "Does this sequence have subsequences which are converging at every point?"

Q2) "Is there a subsequence converging to $0$ at every point of this domain?"

Q3)"What kind of sequence is this?"

Then I would propose the following answers

Ans $1$. Yes, there are subsequences of $f_n$ converging at every point of the domain.

Proof :- If $x\le 0$, then

$f_n(x)=x \quad ,\forall n$ since $1/n\gt 0\ge x ,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

So $\displaystyle{\lim}_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=x$.

Hence every subsequence of $f_n$ converges for $x\le 0$

If $x\gt 0$, then by Archimidean property, $\exists m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/m \lt x$. So $\forall n\gt  m$

$f_n(x)=\cos (nx)$

Now notice that $\{f_n(x)\}_{n\ge m}$ is a bounded sequence and hence has a convergent subsequence.

This proves the claim.

Ans $2$) No, this is not true.

Becuase for $x\lt 0$,

$\displaystyle{\lim}_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=x\lt 0$.

Then how can $f_n$ have a subsequence converging to $0$ for $x\lt 0$.

Ans $3$) I don't really understand what do you mean by "kind of sequence" . If it is for monotone or bounded, then the answer is no as can be easily seen.

Hope this helps.